# Stop an IntentService which is scheduled using alarm manager

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get all the photos from my phone's gallery and hence set them as wallpaper recursively. I am using alarm manager for the purpose. And I want the IntentService to stop as soon as I removed my app from the recent tasks. But there's no way I am able to do so.

My **WallpaperPreferenceActivity** is:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context=getApplicationContext();
        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String s=context.getPackageName();
        Log.e("TAG",s);
        String Interval =" ";
        if ( extras != null ) {
            if ( extras.containsKey ( "Interval" ) ) {
                Interval = extras.getString("Interval");
                int i = Integer.valueOf(Interval);
                updateInterval= i * 1000;
                System.out.println("PeerID: " + Interval);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Interval in extras");
                updateInterval=10000;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No extras");
            updateInterval =10000;
        }
        // Create the intents
        intent = new Intent(WallpaperService.REFRESH_WALLPAPER);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(WallpaperPreferencesActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // Schedule the alarm!
        long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Long refreshIntervalMs = updateInterval;
            Log.d("refreshIntervalMs", refreshIntervalMs.toString());
            // Schedule the alarm
            am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, firstTime, refreshIntervalMs, pendingIntent);

    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.exit(0);
        Log.e("TAG","STOPPED");
    }
```

Can someone tell me how can I stop the service when app is removed from recent tasks??

Comment: The `IntentService` will fire  on `Alarm` . I think the only way to do this cancel the alarm / or Override it .

Comment: use `Service` instead of `intentService` and stop service on both `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` override method.

Comment: I don't want the service to run in the main thread @HemantParmar

Comment: I used cancelling the alarm with override and it worked well. Thanks a lot. @ADM

Comment: Great . Answer your own question then .